# Row width shrinks with every new div, even if each div is the full 12 columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I came across an interesting problem in Bootstrap.

It started as I was creating a form for my website. The input boxes happen to be nested within a few other elements, because that is how I determined the site must be structured. However, it was bothering me that the input boxes were quite small (not enough to see all the text that the user will probably be typing into it).

I tested it out on JSFiddle, and it turns out that as you nest `div`s, even if each one is `<div class="col-lg-12">`, the content gets smaller and smaller. [Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/zb4dc/134/)

My question is, how do I avoid this shrinkage? How can I nest elements yet still maintain a full width?

I'm looking specifically for the "proper" way to do this, not something that will mess up the rest of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that this happens is because bootstrap sets padding on all of it's columns (based on what is set in your variables).

So, every time you add a column inside another column, there's a little bit of padding wrapped around it, and it just keeps building up the more you add.

However, this is part of the purpose of the 'row' class in bootstrap.. It has negative left and right margins set on it that are equal to the padding, allowing for the outer padding on the far left and far right columns to be negated, and producing columns that are flush with their containers.

So, in short, the best solution for you would simply be to ensure that every nested column is, in turn, nested in a row, like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12"> ... </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've updated your fiddle to show this:

http://jsfiddle.net/zb4dc/135/

Comment: Cool, thanks! That's a great answer. Though it gets kind of cluttered real quick

Comment: It does.. The other option is to manually override the padding in your own css, but wether or not that is any less messy could be a bit of a toss-up. This approach at least uses a bootstrap solution for a bootstrap problem, keeps it a bit better contained.